# Meteor Tracker for variable

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a tracker in one of my classes, this class imports a variable from another class that does some computations and returns a array of objects. I am then trying to populate a table with this data. It usually works find when I am pulling data for the db, because the tracker puts a dependency on that that but when I am using an array It does not seem to put a dependency on the variable and only running the tracker once which in turn returns a half empty array.

As you can see in this example I have badDebtsNameSpace is the array variable imported from another class. But it always returns undefined .

```
Tracker.autorun(function() { // Tracker function for reactivity

        if(typeof badDebtsNameSpace.globalDebCalc != "undefined"){
            cashInData[0] = badDebtsNameSpace.globalDebCalc['fromOpeningDeb'];
            cashInTable.loadData(cashInData);

            cashInTable.render();
        }

        console.log(badDebtsNameSpace)



});
```

How ever if I look at the printed data from the console log everything seems to be fine. Any ideas on why this is happening.

Thanks

**Update**

More code as requested. Here is some of the output class that exports the variables.

```
export var prodNameSpace = {};
export var overheadsNameSpace = {};
export var fixedAssetsName = {};
export var fundingNameSpace = {};


export var globalDebCalc;
export var badDebtsNameSpace;

export var productSummary;
export var assetSummary;
export var vatSummary;
export var overheadsSummary;
export var fundingSummary;

//Overheads Tracker TO Calc Data
    Tracker.autorun(function() { // Tracker function for reactivity
        var tempData = Session.get('data');
        var overs = Overhead.find({fileId: tempData._id}).fetch();
        var globalData = GlobalWhatIfData.find({fileId: tempData._id}).fetch();

         if(overs.length > 0 && globalData.length > 0){
            for(var i in overs){
                var percentageOf = PercentageOfData.find({parentId: overs[i]._id}).fetch();
                var vatRef = VatDataRef.find({parentId: overs[i]._id}).fetch();

                if(percentageOf.length > 0 && vatRef.length > 0){
                    var n = overs[i].description;
                    overheadsNameSpace[n] = new OverheadCalc(productSummary, percentageOf, vatRef, globalData);
                }

            }   
            overheadsSummary = new OverheadsCalc(overheadsNameSpace);
         }
    });

    //Bad Debt Tracker 
    Tracker.autorun(function() { // Tracker function for reactivity
        var tempData = Session.get('data');
        var bds = BadDebts.find({fileId: tempData._id}).fetch();
        var globaDeb = GlobalDebtors.find({fileId: tempData._id}).fetch();

        if(bds.length > 0 && globaDeb.length > 0){
            for(var i in bds){
                badDebtsNameSpace = new BadDebtsCalc(bds, productSummary, globaDeb);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: One of the things with trackers is that they require *reactive* data sources in order to be triggered. Is `badDebtsNameSpace.globalDebCalc` a reactive data source? That won't affect whether it's defined or not however, you probably have some other problem with your imports/exports.

Comment: The export are calc done from database data . They are also depening on trackers

Comment: What would think if I used reactive vars some how

Comment: I think we need to see more of your code.

Comment: `badDebtsNameSpace` doesn't look like it's reactive. Also why are you reassigning it `bds` times? That loop makes no sense. What does the `BadDebtsCalc` function return?

Comment: Hey @MichelFloyd I am running the bds time because I want to create a BadDebtsCalc object for each BadDebt return. So just say the user has 3 bad debts it creates a object for each one which does calculations and then that is what i would like to show later. how can I make this reactive. I am probably after going about this all wrong. Thanks for sticking with me here .

Comment: You're actually overwriting the same object over and over. You should create a *reactive array* and then push elements into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a reactive array as I mentioned in the comments but if you don't want to add a package you can use a [tracker dependency](https://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html#tracker_dependency) This basically registers a dependency on some other computation so that `Tracker` can react to it. Also you [shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/500531/2805154) iterate over arrays with `for(var i in array)` Code below:

```
export var prodNameSpace = {};
export var overheadsNameSpace = {};
export var fixedAssetsName = {};
export var fundingNameSpace = {};

export var globalDebCalc;
export var badDebtsNameSpace = [];
export var bdnsDep = new Tracker.Dependency; // register a dependency

export var productSummary;
export var assetSummary;
export var vatSummary;
export var overheadsSummary;
export var fundingSummary;

//Overheads Tracker TO Calc Data
Tracker.autorun(function() { // Tracker function for reactivity
  var id = Session.get('data')._id; // small simplification
  var overs = Overhead.find({fileId: id}).fetch();
  var globalData = GlobalWhatIfData.find({fileId: id}).fetch();

  if(globalData.length){ // you don't need to check >0 as 0 will be *falsy*
    overs.forEach(o=>{
      var percentageOf = PercentageOfData.find({parentId: o._id}).fetch();
      var vatRef = VatDataRef.find({parentId: o._id}).fetch();

      if(percentageOf.length && vatRef.length){
        var n = o.description;
        overheadsNameSpace[n] = new OverheadCalc(productSummary, percentageOf, vatRef, globalData);
      }    
    }   
    overheadsSummary = new OverheadsCalc(overheadsNameSpace);
  }
});

//Bad Debt Tracker 
Tracker.autorun(function() { // Tracker function for reactivity
  var id = Session.get('data')._id;
  var bds = BadDebts.find({fileId: id}).fetch();
  var globaDeb = GlobalDebtors.find({fileId: id}).fetch();

  if(bds.length && globaDeb.length){
    bdnsDep.changed(); // tell the tracker to register the change
    for(var i = 0; i < bds.length; i++){
      badDebtsNameSpace[i] = new BadDebtsCalc(bds, productSummary, globaDeb);
    }
  }
});

Tracker.autorun(function() { // Tracker function for reactivity
  bdnsDep.depend(); // this is where we react to the change
  if( badDebtsNameSpace.globalDebCalc ){ // you don't have to check the type, just check to see if the key exists
    cashInData[0] = badDebtsNameSpace.globalDebCalc['fromOpeningDeb'];
    cashInTable.loadData(cashInData);
    cashInTable.render();
  }   
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much Micheal. I learned alot for this piece of code. Thanks